# View displayed below another view that has a lower elevation in Android

Tags: android, view, elevation

I've run into a seemingly weird problem where a view is displayed below another view with a lower elevation when the view is contained in a parent viewgroup. Below is a code snippet with the simplest example I can make. The views (squares) have the exact same elevation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">


    <!-- Elevation working properly -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/dark_overlay_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:alpha="0.3"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:elevation="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


    <!-- Elevation working properly -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_displayed_above_overlay"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#C8F8C8"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


    <!-- Here's the trouble -->
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/troublesome_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_that_wont_display_above_overlay"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#C8F8C8"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Which displays as the following image:

[Image showing android screen with 2 green squares with the same elevation. However, one of the squares are displayed below a with lower elevation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4844.png)

I have tried changing layout type of both the root and the parent of the view that is displayed, doesn't matter.

I understand that elevation is inherited from the immediate parent of a view, but shouldn't a view be displayed above another if it has a higher elevation?

I have also compared the two squares in the Layout Inspector in Android Studio. The only differences were the x-positions (and the IDs).

To simplify, my goal is to have:

- ViewGroup with no elevation.
- Child-view of that ViewGroup with 8dp elevation
- View (sibling of the ViewGroup) with 7dp elevation being displayed below the child-view.

Comment: It doesn't for me.. You may have copied jantursky's answer, that code produced your image.

Comment: My bad. What I don't get now is how the two squares have different colours when the hex value assigned to both is same.

Comment: They have different colors because one of them (the right one) are displayed below the view that covers the entire screen in black with alpha=0.3. Both squares should look like the left one since they both have a higher elevation than the screen-covering view. But for some reason the right square is displayed below when it is inside a ViewGroup.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite old, but I was facing this problem. Setting `android:translationZ` equal to `android:elevation` value worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to switch assigned elevation to root layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">


    <!-- Elevation working properly -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/dark_overlay_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:alpha="0.3"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:elevation="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


    <!-- Elevation working properly -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_displayed_above_overlay"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#C8F8C8"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


    <!-- Here's the trouble -->
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/troublesome_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_that_wont_display_above_overlay"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#C8F8C8"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: In the app I'm making, that root layout (id 'troublesome_parent') is a ScrollView that will contain other elements with no elevation. This suggestion wont work then.Unless you have a fix for setting a child-view's elevation to 0 when the parent-view have e.g. 8dp elevation?

Comment: Try moving your overlay view into the scroll view